# What is the value of is_nothrow_copy_assignable for a class with a throwing copy constructor and a noexcept by-value copy assignment?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, language-lawyer

What is, in terms of the C++ standard, the expected (if any) output of the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
    A(A const& other) {}
    A(A&& other) noexcept {}
    A& operator=(A other) noexcept { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<A>::value << "\n"
        << std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<A>::value << "\n";
}
```

In other words, does the evaluation of the type traits' values look at the declaration of the assignment operator only, which is noexcept, and does it thus yield

```
true
true
```

Or does it consider the calling context (`a`, `b` are instances of `A`)

```
a = b;            // may throw, implicitly calls copy c'tor
a = std::move(b); // noexcept, implicitly calls move c'tor
```

and does it yield

```
false
true
```

*Practical attempts*

Running the code with Visual Studio 2015, Update 3 gives

```
true
true
```

whereas gcc 6.1 gives

```
false
true
```

Who is right?

*Background*

A situation like this occurs when we have a resource managing class with a throwing copy constructor (since resource allocation may fail), a noexcept move constructor, a throwing copy assignment and a noexcept move assignment.

Supposing that both copy and move assignment can be efficiently implemented in terms of the swap idom:

```
A& operator=(A const& other) {
    A(other).swap(*this); // calls the copy c'tor, may throw
    return *this;
}

A& operator=(A&& other) noexcept {
    A(std::move(other)).swap(*this); // calls noexcept move c'tor
    return *this;
}
```

Then we might consider condensing both into the single by-value copy assignment

```
A& operator=(A other) noexcept {
    other.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

However, we can only safely do this if `std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<A>` and `std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<A>` provide the correct values (false and true, respectively). Otherwise, code relying on these type traits would behave badly and our single by-value assignment would *not* be a correct replacement for two separate assignment operators.

Comment: For `vector`, you need `is_nothrow_move_assignable` to be correct, but not necessarily `is_nothrow_copy_assignable`. Also there's no need to use `boolalpha` twice.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I have edited the question accordingly. Of course, `ìs_nothrow_copy_assignable` should still behave correctly, even if `std::vector` does not require it.

Comment: Actually, I got confused. `vector` requires `is_nothrow_move_constructible` to be correct to get full efficiency during reallocation. I can't recall offhand if anything in it actually wants `is_nothrow_move_assignable`. But yes, regardless of whether `vector` cares about it, traits should behave correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of `is_nothrow_copy_assignable` is in [meta.unary.prop]:

> For a referenceable type `T`, the same result as `is_nothrow_assignable_v<T&, const T&>`, otherwise `false`.

Ok, `A` is referenceable (meaning `A&` is valid). So we go into `is_nothrow_assignable`:

> `is_assignable_v<T, U>` is `true` and the assignment is known not to throw any exceptions (5.3.7).

`is_assignable_v<A, A const&>` is definitely `true`, so we satisfy the first part. What does it mean to be known not to throw any exceptions? According to [expr.unary.noexcept]:

> The `noexcept` operator determines whether the evaluation of its operand, which is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5), can throw an exception (15.1). [...] The result of the `noexcept` operator is `true` if the set of potential exceptions of the expression (15.4) is empty, and false otherwise.

And in [except.spec]:

> The exception-specification `noexcept` or `noexcept(constant-expression)`, where the constant-expression yields `true`, denotes an exception specification that is the empty set. The exception-specification `noexcept(constant-expression)`, where the *constant-expression* yields `false`, or the absence of an *exception-specification* in a function declarator other than that for a destructor (12.4) or a deallocation function (3.7.4.2) denotes an
>   exception specification that is the set of all types.

And:

> The set of potential exceptions of an expression e is empty if e is a core constant expression (5.20). Otherwise,
>   it is the union of the sets of potential exceptions of the immediate sub-expressions of e, including default
>   argument expressions used in a function call, combined with a set S defined by the form of e, as follows: [...]
>   — If e implicitly invokes one or more functions (such as an overloaded operator, an allocation function in a new-expression, or a destructor if e is a full-expression (1.9)), S is the union of:
>      — the sets of types in the exception specifications of all such functions, and
>      — if e is a new-expression [...]

Now, the assignment of an `A` from an `A const&` involves two steps:

1. invoking the copy constructor of `A`
2. invoking the copy assignment operator of `A`

The exception specification is the union of all the exception specifications of both of these functions, which is the set of all types - because the copy constructor does not have an *exception-specification* at all.

Therefore, `is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<A>` should be `false`. gcc is correct.

Comment: The question is really what "the assignment" means: the invocation of the assignment operator alone, or the entire assignment expression. I don't think there's any doubt that it should return false if the latter is meant (and it is).

Comment: @T.C. I think if it meant specifically the assignment operator, it would've said that - and that'd wouldn't be very practical anyway.